# How to add server in Minecraft 1.12.2 in Xbox One?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, xbox-one, minecraft-bedrock-edition-server

My **Minecraft Xbox One Edition** got an update recently, and I have version 1.12.2, which is just called **Minecraft** now.

I used to play on a PC, now called Java Edition. There is a Multiplayer button, after that, I got the chance to "Add Server", where I can add my own server (on an Ubuntu machine), which is 192.168.1.x.

What is this function in Xbox One? I can see **Servers**, which only listed some **featured servers**. Where is the place I add our own server in Xbox One?

Comment: I didn't play Bedrock Edition (which is the name of all platforms except Java after 1.12) yet, but the [wiki](https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Featured_servers) says `In the console versions, they (featured servers) are the only servers accessible besides Realms`. You may be out of luck there.

Comment: Then how can we register our local server as a "featured"? Is it possible?

Comment: Of course :-) You need to create a really cool server, register a company, contact Mojang and prove them your server is worth featuring :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: you can't.

The new [better together update](https://minecraft.net/en-us/article/better-together-faq) allows cross-platform play, but only between the Xbox One S, Xbox One X, Android, iPhone, iPad, Apple TV, Windows 10, Windows Phone, Amazon Fire tablets, Gear VR and eventually the Nintendo Switch edition.

**NOTE**: When it says Windows 10 it means the [Windows 10 Edition](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/p/minecraft-for-windows-10/9nblggh2jhxj), which is different from the Java version for PC/Mac.

As Augustas said, you can't play in a friends world if he is not active. However, if you or a friend purchases a **realms** subscription, it will be perpetually available so long as you keep paying the fee.
 ($3.99/mo. for up to 3 simultaneous players, up to $7.99/mo. for up to 11 simultaneous players). Only one person needs to pay this fee - all friends play free. If you want something akin to a Java edition server, *this is as close as you can get*.

Also, just since you didn't mention it in your question, you do need an Xbox Live Gold membership to be able to access Realms on Xbox One, though it is not needed for other versions.

Answer (score 3):

I am running 3 servers using [*phantom*](https://github.com/jhead/phantom) and I can join them with Xbox One. *phantom* can be run on Linux, Raspberry Pi or Windows.

Description:

> *phantom* makes hosted Bedrock/MCPE servers show up as LAN servers, specifically
> for Xbox. You can now play on remote servers (not Realms!) on your
> Xbox with friends. It's like having a LAN server that's not actually
> there, spooky.
>
> #### How does this work?
>
> On Minecraft platforms that support LAN servers, the game will
> broadcast a server ping packet to every device on the same network and
> display any valid replies as connectable servers. This tool runs on
> your computer - desktop, laptop, Raspberry Pi, etc. - and pretends to
> be a LAN server, acting as a proxy, passing all traffic from your game
> through your computer and to the server (and back), so that Minecraft
> thinks you're connected to a LAN server, but you're really playing on
> a remote server. As soon as you start it up, you should see the fake
> server listed under LAN and, upon selecting it, connect to the real
> Bedrock/MCPE server hosted elsewhere.
>
> For an optimal experience, run this on a device that is connected via
> ethernet and not over WiFi, since a wireless connection could
> introduce some lag. Your game device can be connected to WiFi. Your
> remote server can be running on a computer, a VM, or even with a
> Minecraft hosting service.

Comment: I'm not following.  I can *already* see my multiplayer game running on my Linux PC *locally* from my XBox One.  But my friends can't see it if they aren't on my LAN - what do you mean by "remote servers" exactly?

Answer (score 0):

In console, whether its ps or xbox you can't create servers. The only thing you can call server is minigames, where online players meets. However it cant be edited or created, its created by minecraft itself as default servers with its specific maps and rules. Anyway you can play with friend by joining in friend's world. You cant play in friends world if he's not active. Maximum allowed players amount is 4.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, you cannot add your own servers on Minecraft on Xbox, BUT their is a chance that in a future update will allow players to add their own servers. Right now, this new Minecraft is only in beta, so their are still some updates to come.